# Is there a way to avoid memory leak when executing a code that outlive the caller

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, memory-leaks, kotlin-coroutines

Hello hope someone can help me.

**Problem**: In **code #1**. The code inside "onListenerDisconnected" will not finish executing because the coroutine will be cancelled via onDestroy.

**code #1**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class NotificationService : NotificationListenerService() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var updateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase: UpdateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase

    private val job = SupervisorJob()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)

    override fun onListenerConnected() {
        scope.launch {
            updateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase.execute(
                UpdateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase.Companion.Param(
                    isActive = true
                )
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onListenerDisconnected() {
        scope.launch {
            updateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase.execute(
                UpdateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase.Companion.Param(
                    isActive = false
                )
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (job.isActive) {
            job.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

**My defective Solution**: Use a coroutine that outlive the service lifecycle which in this case I used a coroutine that is attached to the application lifecycle. but when I do this leak canary detects memory leak says that NotificationService is leaking

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class NotificationService : NotificationListenerService() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var updateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase: UpdateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase

    @Inject
    lateinit var lifeCycleScope: CoroutineScope

    override fun onListenerConnected() {
        lifeCycleScope.launch {
            updateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase.execute(
                UpdateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase.Companion.Param(
                    isActive = true
                )
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onListenerDisconnected() {
        lifeCycleScope.launch {
            updateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase.execute(
                UpdateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase.Companion.Param(
                    isActive = false
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**:

1. Should I be concerned with the memory leak that leak canary detects or is this just a small price and can be ignored to achieve what i want to do?

```
┬───
│ GC Root: Global variable in native code
│
├─ android.service.notification.
│  NotificationListenerService$NotificationListenerWrapper instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 2.5 kB in 35 objects
│    this$0 instance of link.limecode.histotify.services.NotificationService
│    ↓ NotificationListenerService$NotificationListenerWrapper.this$0
│                                                              ~~~~~~
╰→ link.limecode.histotify.services.NotificationService instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because link.limecode.
​     histotify.services.NotificationService received Service#onDestroy()
​     callback and Service not held by ActivityThread)
​     Retaining 1.9 kB in 34 objects
​     key = 1532cc3d-e8d6-40dc-81d4-914260acb10d
​     watchDurationMillis = 18592
​     retainedDurationMillis = 13584
​     mApplication instance of link.limecode.histotify.HistotifyApp
​     mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl
 
METADATA
 
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 29
Build.MANUFACTURER: HUAWEI
LeakCanary version: 2.10
App process name: link.limecode.histotify
Class count: 16160
Instance count: 130077
Primitive array count: 93652
Object array count: 18860
Thread count: 26
Heap total bytes: 17295269
Bitmap count: 11
Bitmap total bytes: 8450411
Large bitmap count: 0
Large bitmap total bytes: 0
Db 1: open /data/user/0/link.limecode.histotify/databases/leaks.db
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=34712,misses=89445,hitRate=27%]
RandomAccess[bytes=4417411,reads=89445,travel=29347908102,range=21153586,size=26
687475]
Analysis duration: 7242 ms
```

2. If this memory leak cant be ignored what other way can I do this without memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem in the second solution with the injected CoroutineScope is that the coroutine is capturing a reference to your whole class because it uses the `updateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase` property of that class. So, copy the value of that property to a local variable before you launch the coroutine and use only the local variable in the coroutine:

```
override fun onListenerConnected() {
    val useCase = updateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase
    lifeCycleScope.launch {
        useCase.execute(
            UpdateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase.Companion.Param(
                isActive = true
            )
        )
    }
}
```

"`lifeCycleScope`" seems to be a misleading name for this scope since you explicitly designed it to outlive this class's lifecycle.

Comment: yes your right I think "lifeCycleScope" is misleading here thank you. You gave me an idea on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tenfour04 that gave me an idea on how to solve this. Instead of injecting the lifecyclescope inside the service I injected it inside the usecase. I have verified it with leak canary and it says all retained objects are garbage collected

```
class UpdateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val appPreferenceRepository: AppPreferenceRepository,
    private val lifeCycleScope: CoroutineScope
) : NonSuspendingBaseUseCase<UpdateIsNotificationServiceActiveUseCase.Companion.Param, Unit> {

    companion object {
        data class Param(
            val isActive: Boolean
        )
    }

    override fun execute(param: Param): Result<Unit> {
        lifeCycleScope.launch {
            appPreferenceRepository.setIsNotificationServiceActive(value = param.isActive)
        }
        return Result.Success(Unit)
    }
}
```